# capture incorporating domain name inside iframe on gtag event_label

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics

OK! Let me explain my need:

I have a domain which produces an iframe that is available to other users embed on their sites.

**Here is the code rendered by that `iframe`:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<body>
<a href="#" onClick="gtag('event', 'myevent', {'event_category': 'mycategory', 'event_label': '+window.location.hostname '});">see</a>

<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX-XX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX-XX',{ 'anonymize_ip': true });
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that I need to have statistics on my analytics account from each site that embeds my iframe to be informed on how much clicks that link has.

If you noticed the code above, you will see that I try to use the javascript `window.location.hostname` to capture the embedder domain name on the analytics `event_label` without success.

Can this be done? if so, how?

Please remember that this iframe is always embedded on other domains.